# Can't implement searchable spinner in my android studio

Tags: android, kotlin, android-studio, gradle-dependencies

I want to implement searchable spinner in my android studio Hedgehog (Kotlin), but it keeps error. does anyone know why or can give me another implementation source?
"implementation project(path: ':searchablespinner')"

dependencies {

```
implementation("androidx.core:core-ktx:1.9.0")
implementation("androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.6.1")
implementation("com.google.android.material:material:1.10.0")
implementation("androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.1.4")

testImplementation("junit:junit:4.13.2")
androidTestImplementation("androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.5")
androidTestImplementation("androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.5.1")

implementation ("com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.9.0")
implementation ("com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.9.0")
implementation ("com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.16.0")
implementation ("com.squareup.okhttp3:logging-interceptor:4.11.0")

implementation ("androidx.cardview:cardview:1.0.0")

implementation ("com.airbnb.android:lottie:6.1.0")
implementation ("androidx.viewpager2:viewpager2:1.0.0")
implementation ("me.relex:circleindicator:2.1.6")
implementation ("androidx.swiperefreshlayout:swiperefreshlayout:1.1.0")

implementation ("androidx.activity:activity-ktx:1.8.1")
implementation(platform("com.google.firebase:firebase-bom:32.6.0"))
implementation ("com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore-ktx")

implementation("org.apache.poi:poi:5.2.5")
implementation("org.apache.poi:poi-ooxml:5.2.5")

implementation ("com.github.PhilJay:MPAndroidChart:v3.1.0")

implementation ("androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel-ktx:2.6.1")
implementation ("androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-livedata-ktx:2.6.1")
implementation ("androidx.activity:activity-ktx:1.7.2")

implementation ("androidx.datastore:datastore-preferences:1.0.0")
implementation ("androidx.room:room-runtime:2.5.1")
kapt ("androidx.room:room-compiler:2.5.1")


implementation ("com.github.alvinhkh:TextDrawable:c1c2b5b")
implementation project(path: ':searchablespinner')
```

}

I have tried another format such as :
implementation project(path: ':searchablespinner')
implementation project(path: ":searchablespinner")
implementation (project(path: ':searchablespinner'))
implementation ("project(path: ':searchablespinner')")

Comment: welcome to stack overflow. what's the error you're getting ?

Comment: Failed to resolve: project(path: ':searchablespinner')

Comment: What is a 'searchable spinner' to begin with?

Comment: It's a dropdown/spinner but also can be selected by typing (search)

Comment: where does `searchablespinner` come from ? is it a project you have that you want to add or do you want to use it like your other dependencies (meaning that it is hosted somewhere online) ?

Comment: And what should be searchable in a spinner? Where would you use it for? You might tell something more. And can be selected? How would you select a spinner? And where are you typing to begin with?

Comment: @blackapps not sure if `what does it do` is relevant here. OP is trying to add a dependency and in the process of adding it, they're having problems. what that dependency should do (right or wrong) isn't really what the question is about, imo. it could have been anything